# Include Javascript inside Update Panel Not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to include javascript from remote source inside update panel,This code is to include facebook and twitter share buttons in my application.here is the code:

This works fine when the page is loaded first time, but when the page is postback with ajax, the script doesnot work, can anybody help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post some code you use and give some more details on the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to include code into an update panel? I think updating javascript works well with UpdatePanels in case you use the regular script manager.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx

Comment: Actually i am using the Facebook and twitter share buttons on my page. and need to include a script inside a table which is inside the update panel. what to do.